# Como saber o nome da ActionResult que chamou a view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

Gostaria de saber se é possível pegar o nome da `ActionResult` que chamou a `View`.
Eu sei que normalmente a `View` tem o mesmo nome da `ActionResult`, mas no meu caso, tenho uma única view para duas `ActionResult` diferentes, dai dentro da `View` preciso saber em qual das duas `ActionResult` farei o *POST*.

Seria algo do tipo:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(ACTION_RESULT_QUE_CHAMOU_A_VIEW, "MeuController", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

### **Atualização**

Eu consegui pegar o ActionResult dinamicamente com:

```
ViewBag.ActionResult = ViewContext.RequestContext.RouteData.Values.Values.Where(w => w.Equals("Edit") || w.Equals("Create")).First().ToString();
```

Não sei se é a melhor forma, se não for por favor, me digam.

Só que agora tive outro problema. Quando chamo meu BeginForm dessa maneira:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(ViewBag.ActionResult, "MeuController", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
```

Recebo o seguinte erro na página:

> Os métodos de extensão não podem ser expedidos dinamicamente.
>   Considere converter os argumentos dinâmicos ou chamar o método de
>   extensão sem a sintaxe do método.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim:

`ActionResult` `Create` e `Edit` chama a mesma `View` `CreateEdit`

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
    return View("CreateEdit");
}
public ActionResult Edit()
{
    return View("CreateEdit");
}
```

Pegar automáticamente a `ActionResult` que foi chamada

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(), 
            "Geral", 
            FormMethod.Post, 
            new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{               

}
```

Se quiser pegar o `ActionResult` e o `Controller` coloque assim?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(Html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["action"].ToString(),
            Html.ViewContext.Controller.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString(),
            FormMethod.Post, 
            new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
{

}
```

Ao postar esses formulários respectivamente cairão nos seus `ActionResult`

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(FormCollection form)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Create");
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(FormCollection form)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Edit");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Isto é porque você usou um elemento da `ViewBag` pra chamar o `HtmlHelper`.

Isto resolve:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(ViewBag.ActionResult.ToString(), "MeuController", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal" })) { ... }
```

Comment: Cigano, Obrigado! Isso resolve a minha última dúvida. Marquei a do @HarryPotter como resposta porque a dele resolve todo o problema.